# multitrigger on custom view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I created a custom view called "InfoButton":

```cs
public class InfoButton : ImageButton
{
    public string Glyph { get; set; } = "\U000F02FD";
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public InfoButton()
    {
        Source = new FontImageSource() { Glyph = Glyph, FontFamily = "materialdesign.ttf#materialdesign", Size= (double)new FontSizeConverter().ConvertFromInvariantString("Title"), Color = Color.Black };
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        Clicked += InfoButton_Clicked;
    }

    private void InfoButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlertPopup.DisplayAlertPopup(Title, Text, 0, "Close");
    }
}
```

Now I created a Trigger for it:

```xml
<models:InfoButton Glyph="&#xF059F;" Title="some title" Text="some text" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
    <models:InfoButton.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="{x:Type models:InfoButton}">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding isPublic}" Value="true"/>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding isReadonly}" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="Glyph" Value="&#xF059F;"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </models:InfoButton.Triggers>
</models:InfoButton>
```

But I get this error while compiling:

> XFC0001   Cannot resolve property "Glyph" on type "InfoButton (property missing or missing accessors)".

What could be the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To simply fix your issue go to **Solution** section. To know the reason why your code is failing see **Explanation** section.*

### Solution

You will have to turn your `Glyph` property into a **BindableProperty** as follows

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty GlyphProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Glyph), typeof(string), typeof(InfoButton), "\U000F02FD");

public string Glyph
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(GlyphProperty); }
    set { SetValue(GlyphProperty, value); }
}
```

### Explanation

The explanation why your code is failing with `Glyph` defined as a simple property can be found in [the docu for **Setter.Property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.setter.property?view=xamarin-forms#remarks) where it says

> Only bindable properties can be set with a Setter.